# JS drawImage as a method in class

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, drawimage

I started a simple project in javascript a few days ago and found this issue. Every time I reload my google-page i get an empty canvas. I have already tried to take out the drawImage() function out of class and it worked. But what if I need to use that function as a class method? (Also I've already tried passing the canvas as an argument of the draw method but it doesn't work)

So this is working but I don't need it

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('main_canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

var img = new Image()
img.src = 'some source'
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10)
```

And this isn't working but supposed to

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('main_canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

class Person
{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name
    this.img = new Image()
    this.img.src = 'some source'
  }
  draw(){
    ctx.drawImage(this.img,10,10)
  }
}

var peter = new Person('Peter Griffin')
peter.draw()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple. Your image is not loaded when you want to draw it.

You have to wait until the image is loaded before drawing it in the canvas.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('main_canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

class Person
{
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
        this.img = new Image()
        this.img.src = 'monimage.jpg'
    }
    on_image_loaded(f) {
        this.img.onload = f;
    }
    draw(){
        ctx.drawImage(this.img,10,10)
    }
}

var peter = new Person('Peter Griffin')
peter.on_image_loaded(function() {
    peter.draw();
});
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much! I mean, I used onload but it didn't work but your code solved my 3-day problem